# How to connect remote Linux box through PHP in windows environment

Tags: php, linux, wamp, remote-access, putty

I'm on a Windows XP machine, with Wamp installed. Currently, I am using putty to connect my remote Linux boxes.

I want to execute Linux commands through php shell_exec() method (cp, ls, ...).

Does anybody know how to connect my Linux box first and then run those commands in a Windows environment?

Any advice's would be highly appreciated...

Comment: so you want to connect from the linux box ssh to your windows wamp?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run `Linux` commands in `Windows`. 
You can run them over `SSH`, using `putty`. It seems you have that running.

You can forward the connection over ssh. Look in the putty screen, go to `Connection > SSH > Tunnels`.

Then you add a tunnel:

```
source port: 1234 
destination port: localhost:80
type is Local
```

So you open `Internet Explorer`, type in the addres bar: `http://localhost:1234` the port `1234` is then forwarded to the port `80` on the remote linux pc.

You can also forward it to the WAMP by setting

```
destination port: *ip of the wamp server*:80
```

Then you can acces the `Windows` pc from outside the network, as long as `putty` is running.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a PHP script on Windows to run SSH commands on a remote Linux server. For this, see [the PHP SSH2 extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php).

> Bindings to the libssh2 library which provide access to resources
>   (shell, remote exec, tunneling, file transfer) on a remote machine
>   using a secure cryptographic transport.

This will allow you to connect to the Linux server via SSH and execute commands on the remove server (`cp`, `ls`, etc.). Here's some sample code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'hostname');
echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($stream);
```

It's worth noting that this probably isn't the safest or most reliable way to go about this task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can execute linux commands on a windows machine.

You might want to consider using [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/)
and skip the php.

But you will get you a Windows Shell. `C:\\>` and no `ls` or `cp`, but otherwise full control.

You could also get experimental and run a Virtual machine with linux and share your windows drive with it.

`remote server linux` - - ssh - - > `local virtual linux` - - - shared folder - - > `windows`

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Install [CYGWIN](http://www.cygwin.com/)
- Install [SSH2 extension for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php)

There is an extended SSH2 class I use, which can be found here: [SSH2 with Exception Handling](http://www.highonphp.com/php-ssh2-class-with-exception-handling).